# An efficient way to calculate the mean lap time for each year

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working with the dataset called "AUSTRALIAN GRAND PRIX" found [here](https://www.sportsvizsunday.com/formula-1).

It has this form

```
Year   driverId   position    time    lap    seconds
```

Where there are position*lap observations for each year. The "position" number is not constant as it varies a bit depending on the number of teams that year, and it can vary with laps if a car has to retire during the race as it then stops recording new laps. "Time" variable can be ignored entirely.

I want to calculate the mean lap time for each year 1996 up to 2019, so that I can plot and analyze how lap times have improved / varied over the years (correlation etc)

I know how to do it completely manually but that is obviously extremely tedious and not very elegant. Is there a nice way of doing it without creating new datasets like this

```
Lap_data <- read.csv()

newdat <- Lap_data[Lap_data$year == 1996,]
mean(newdat$seconds)
> [1] 99.02105
```

My end goal is to to be able to `plot(x,y)` , `cor(x,y)` etc where

```
x = [1996, 1997, 1998, ..., 2019]
y = [99.02105, ,mean lap time 1997, ... ,mean lap time 2019]
```

Excuse me if question is badly posed/explained, I'm not sure how to show what the data set looks like as it has 20k observations other than linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` package will help you here. After reading in the data, we `group_by` year, and `summarize` the "seconds" variable into an annual mean:

```r
library(dplyr)

# This is the actual url for the csv file:
url <- paste0("https://10d9b011-755b-4b59-9f64-dbfb2ae95d87.filesusr.com/",
                      "ugd/0c24ab_a29a977ec1404b69bf7cc34fcc58b073.csv?",
                      "dn=Aus%20GP%20Lap%20Data.csv")

df <- read.csv(url) %>%
        group_by(Year) %>% 
        summarize(lap_mean = mean(seconds))
```

So now our data looks like this:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 24 x 2
#>     Year lap_mean
#>    <int>    <dbl>
#>  1  1996     99.0
#>  2  1997     96.3
#>  3  1998     97.9
#>  4  1999    102. 
#>  5  2000     99.8
#>  6  2001    105. 
#>  7  2002    107. 
#>  8  2003    100. 
#>  9  2004     90.8
#> 10  2005     90.3
#> # ... with 14 more rows
```

And we can do simple stats:

```r
cor(df$Year, df$lap_mean)
#> [1] -0.1696682
```

Or create a simple plot:

```r
plot(df$Year, df$lap_mean)
```

[image]

Or even create a more sophisticated plot quite easily:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Year, lap_mean)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme_bw()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me a lot.

Comment: Since you have already worked with this data set now, do you have any tips on a nice way to calculate the relative frequency of winning the race from pole position? That is the number of occurrences where driverId of position 1 is the same for lap 1 and lap 58.